# Get and display a specific Meta Data item for a current user in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to get and display a specific meta data item for a user in wordpress. The value for the data i want to get is that for Event Date. I tried the following code but no luck

```
<?php 
  $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
  $key = 'Event Date';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

Where Event Date is the custom meta field Ive added to the user profile.

Please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I managed to figure this out and it works with the following code:

```
<?php 
     $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
     $key = 'Event Date'; 
     $single = true; 
     $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
     echo $user_last; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find any problem with your code as far as using the Wordpress helper functions. But I see that you are using the wrong variables `$user_ID` and `$user_id` check your code.